# Boostrap 4 - vertically align row to the bottom of a container

Tags: bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble aligning a row of buttons to the **bottom** of a container.

Referencing the screenshot below; There are 3 columns inside a row that make up each section. The row uses the class 'justify-content-center' to center the items in the middle of the page.

The height of the rows grow depending on column with the most content.

My goal is to align the buttons of the second and third column to the bottom of the column so there are inline with the first column.

I've been through Bootstrap documentation and tried many different approached just as 'align-self-send' but still no success.

[image]

Here is my markup;

```
        <div
      class="row justify-content-center package-sections"
    >
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-4 p-2 package package-1">
        <h3 class="mb-3">x</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center learn-more">
            <button
              @click="
                setPackageProperties(x, x)
              "
              v-b-modal.packages-modal
              class="btn btn-learn-more"
            >
              Learn More...
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-center enquire-now">
            <router-link
              to="#contact"
              v-scroll-to="'#contact'"
              class="btn btn-enquire"
              >Enquire Now!</router-link
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-4 p-2 package package-2">
        <h3 class="mb-3">x</h3>
        <p class="pl-3">x</p>
        <ul>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center learn-more">
            <button
              @click="
                setPackageProperties(x, x)
              "
              v-b-modal.packages-modal
              class="btn btn-learn-more"
            >
              Learn More...
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-center enquire-now">
            <router-link
              to="#contact"
              v-scroll-to="'#contact'"
              class="btn btn-enquire"
              >Enquire Now!</router-link
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-4 p-2 package package-3">
        <h3 class="mb-3">x</h3>
        <p class="pl-3">x</p>
        <ul>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
          <li>x</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center learn-more">
            <button
              @click="
                setPackageProperties(x, x)
              "
              v-b-modal.packages-modal
              class="btn btn-learn-more"
            >
              Learn More...
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-center enquire-now">
            <router-link
              to="#contact"
              v-scroll-to="'#contact'"
              class="btn btn-enquire"
              >Enquire Now!</router-link
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note: any custom CSS classes are just styling text or applying colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex, add `.d-flex .flex-column` to your `div.package`s and `.flex-grow-1` to the nested element you want to grow to fill the space.

In the example below I just added a `div.flex-grow-1` after the `ul` but you could just apply that class directly to the `ul`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center package-sections">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-4 p-2 package package-1 d-flex flex-column">
    <h3 class="mb-3">x</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center learn-more">
        <button @click="
                setPackageProperties(x, x)
              " v-b-modal.packages-modal class="btn btn-learn-more">
           Learn More...
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center enquire-now">
        <router-link to="#contact" v-scroll-to="'#contact'" class="btn btn-enquire">Enquire Now!</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-4 p-2 package package-2 d-flex flex-column">
    <h3 class="mb-3">x</h3>
    <p class="pl-3">x</p>
    <ul>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col text-center learn-more">
        <button @click="
                setPackageProperties(x, x)
              " v-b-modal.packages-modal class="btn btn-learn-more">
           Learn More...
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center enquire-now">
        <router-link to="#contact" v-scroll-to="'#contact'" class="btn btn-enquire">Enquire Now!</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-4 p-2 package package-3 d-flex flex-column">
    <h3 class="mb-3">x</h3>
    <p class="pl-3">x</p>
    <ul>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
      <li>x</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center learn-more">
        <button @click="
                setPackageProperties(x, x)
              " v-b-modal.packages-modal class="btn btn-learn-more">
           Learn More...
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col text-center enquire-now">
        <router-link to="#contact" v-scroll-to="'#contact'" class="btn btn-enquire">Enquire Now!</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#direction
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink

Answer (score 1):

check below code I write description after tag for your understanding. You have to do same in your remaining columns which are package 2 and package 3 I guess.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-4 p-2 package package-1 d-flex flex-column"> -- **your col div add d-flex flex-column classes**

... 

    <div class="row mt-auto">  --- **your buttons div add mt-auto class**
          ...
    </div>

</div>
```